# Performance between calling a Class property vs a Class method in PHP?

Tags: php, performance

I know this will not be noticeable at all but just for the sake of learning, is there any overhead of calling class methods over calling a class property like I show in the example below for the $router->controller and $router->action ?  Please don't flame me about premature optimization, just trying to learn more.

```
// Using Class property
$router = new Router($uri, $uri_route_map);
$router->dispatch($router->controller, $router->action);

// Using Class methods instead
$router = new Router($uri, $uri_route_map);
$router->dispatch($router->controller(), $router->action());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$router->controller` is **accessing** a class property, basically just **reading** a variable.
`$router->controller()` is **calling** a function. Calling a function is bound to have more overhead than reading a variable, especially since the function itself will probably read a variable.

Comment: Note that if Router::controller is not public, accessing the property outside of the class results in a call to `__get('controller')` if it exists. If that does string manipulation behind the scenes to determine the actual property (common in Zend Framework to turn it into `'_controller'`), it's even slower. What happens will really depend on the class you're accessing. Router::controller could even be an object that implements `__invoke()`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're learning, try it yourself in a timer script to get a rough estimate:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $property1 = 'a';

    public function method1()
    {
        return $this->property1;
    }
}

$mc = new MyClass();

$start = 0; $end = 0;

// property
$start = microtime(true);
for ($a=0; $a<10000; $a++) {
    $mc->property1; 
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $start . "<br />\n";

// method
$start = microtime(true);
for ($b=0; $b<10000; $b++) {
    $mc->method1();
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo $end - $start . "<br />\n";
```

Output:
0.0040628910064697
0.0082359313964844

Comment: thanks for the example, this will be good to know when designing a large app